# Showing absolute convergence for series representation of $\frac{z}{exp(z) - 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I would appreciate help (self-study) in showing that the related power series of
$\frac{z}{exp(z) - 1}$ converges absolutely for $|z| < 2\pi$ without looking at the specific terms of the series.

(I do know the series, other than the first two terms, consists of a series with coefficients that include Bernoulli numbers and that series can be shown to converge absolutely by comparing $\zeta$-functions and applying the results to the series. Stopple's "Primer of Analytic Number Theory" - Solutions page 358.)

But I was wondering if you can make that determination using theorem(s) from complex analysis.

I am able to show the function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations and is thus analytic with a convergent power series.

What I have thought of is applying a lemma from "Flanigan" page 203:

If the series $\sum {a_k(z - z_0)^k}$ converges at the point $z_1$, then it converges absolutely for all points such that $|z - z_0| < |z_1 - z_0|$.

Using $z_0 = 0$. I realize there will be a pole at $2\pi i$. But if I substitute $z = 2\pi$ in the function, there should be no problem?

But I am not comfortable with my line of thinking because if I substitute $z = 3\pi$ and if there is "no problem" then, in that the theorem says all points, the series should converge for $z = 2\pi i$.

I would appreciate help with the first question and correction regarding what seems like a misunderstanding of the lemma.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The function $e^z-1$ has no zeros in the disk $D=\{ \vert z\vert<1/2\}$ except $z=0$. So your function $f$ is holomorphic in $D\setminus\{ 0\}$; and since it also has a removable singularity at $z=0$, it is in fact holomorphic in $D$ (with $f(0)=1$). Hence, it can be expanded in power series in the whole disk $D$. As for $z=3\pi$, there is a problem because the radius of convergence of the Taylor series at $z_0=0$ is equal to $2\pi$ (due to the pole at $2i\pi$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is analytic except at points where $e^z=1$, i.e. where $z=2\pi i n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. You can check that $z=0$ is a removable singularity, so the Maclaurin series for $f$ will converge (absolutely and locally uniformly) on the largest disc on which $f$ is analytic, hence on $|z|<2\pi$.

Comment: I am embarrassed to ask this; but does a Taylor/Maclaurin series always converge absolutely and uniformly on the largest disk as you indicate? (I did forget to mention the removable singularity.) Also do you have any comment please regarding my confusion with the lemma I mentioned? Thanks. With regards,

Comment: Yes. And if you substitute $z=3\pi$ into the *power series* you will get divergence. You shouldn't think of the power series and the analytic (or meromorphic) function as the **same** thing. They are not, even though the power series converges to $f(z)$ on *its disc of convergence*.